# Is there a way to call a tidyverse created data frame inside a ggplot2 two or more times?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a graph in ggplot2 and trying to highlight or differenciate one of the factor for the other ones, the next code can reproduce what I'm trying to do with a red point for Datsun 710 car:

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car")

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(car, mpg), 
             y = mpg, 
             label = mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = if_else(mtcars$car == "Datsun 710", "Red", "Black")) +
  geom_text(size = 3, hjust = -0.2) + 
  coord_flip()
```

But I want to do it withouth calling the df again on the eigth line: **mtcars$car**, and not depend on a df outside of the ggplot first df argument.

Is it possible?

Comment: You're already using `dplyr` pipes, why not define color before `ggplot` and just reference a column?

Comment: Or straight in `aes`. Simpler example: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, color = cyl == 4)) + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black"))`

Comment: Wrap it in a function with a parameter x that is the name of the data frame.  I would advise against overwriting mtcars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dot within brace brackets:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  { ggplot(., aes(x = fct_reorder(car, mpg), y = mpg, label = mpg)) +
    geom_point(color = if_else(.$car == "Datsun 710", "Red", "Black")) +
    geom_text(size = 3, hjust = -0.2) + 
    coord_flip()
  }
```

Comment: You don't think it would be better to do that `if_else` inside the `aes`?

Comment: @camille, that would be a good solution here but it does mean that every geom would inherit it and the general problem defined in the subject is to be able to refer to the input twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function that forces use of the same data frame.

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car")

foo <- function(x){
  x %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(car, mpg), 
             y = mpg, 
             label = mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = if_else(x$car == "Datsun 710", "Red", "Black")) +
  geom_text(size = 3, hjust = -0.2) + 
  coord_flip()
}

foo(mtcars2)
```

However note that if it is a tibble the $ notation will not work and you need to use pull().

I don't see much benefit in piping here, though.